# Solve Recurrence for T(n) = 7T(n/7) + n

Tags: recurrence, master-theorem

I'm trying to solve the recurrence for `T(n) = 7T(n/7) + n`.
I know using Master Theorem it's `O(nlog7n)`, but I want to solve it by substitution.

At level i, I get: `7^i T(n/7^i) + (n+7n+7^2n+ .... + 7^i n)`
By setting `i = log7n`, the above becomes:  `7^(log7n)*T(1) + (n + 7n + 7^2n ..... + 7^(log7n) n`

Since `7^log7n = n`, the above finally becomes `n+ (n+7n+(7^2)n+ ....n*n)`
This solves to `O(n^2)` to me not `O(nlog7n)`, any idea what's wrong?

Comment: This would be better at cs.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, will post on that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
T(n)=7T(n/7)+n=7[7T(n/72)+n/7]+n=72T(n/72)+2n=...=7kT(n/7k)+kn
n/7k=c ⇒ k=O(logn)
⇒T(n)=O(nlogn)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @FlyingFoX It's not code, it's mathematical expansion. There is no need for additional info here. If you want to get acquainted with broader aspects of math that lead to these results, you're welcome to read any book on recurrences/computational complexity - but it's out of scope for this site.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.Looks like there is a mistake in my  second part of the equation: `(n+7n+7^2n+ .... + 7^i n)`, I forgot to multiple `7^i` for each of them, they should be able to generalized to `kn` like @SomeWittyUsername mentioned